# Receiving the following error while attempting to compare struct member values

Tags: c#, list, struct

I've just begun to discover the world of c#.
I've been working with a user-defined type
which is the following:

```
struct Obstacle
    {
        public static int x1 { get; set; }
        public static int y1 { get; set; }
        public static int x2 { get; set; }
        public static int y2 { get; set; }

        public Obstacle(int X1, int Y1, int X2, int Y2)
        {
            x1 = X1;
            y1 = Y1;
            x2 = X2;
            y2 = Y2;
        }
    }
```

I construct a list of these types inside classA contained by a different file.

```
List<Obstacle> o = new();
```

Following the procedure of adding elements to the list
I attempt to compare two coordinates of a specififc list element (also inside classA):

```
for (int i = 0; i < obstacle_count; i++)
{
   if (o.ElementAt(i).x1 != obstacles.ElementAt(i).x2)
   {
        //do something
   }
   else
   {
        //do something else
   }
}
```

However I get errors like this one: "Member 'Obstacle.x1' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead".

The struct definition shares namespace with the other code snippets presented above.

How should I resolve the problem? Thx in advance. :)

Comment: members x1, x2, y1,y2 are static, meaning that all objects of type Obstacle share those fields. Should they really be static in your case?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's because x1, x2 , ... are static. You can not affect an static value with a function :)